# AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'list'

Tags: python, python-3.x

**We have to find out the average of a list of numbers entered through keyboard**

```
n=0
a=''
while n>=0:
    a=input("Enter number: ")
    n+=1
    if int(a)==0:
        break
print(sum(int(a.list()))/int(n))
```

Answer (score 2):

You are not saving the numbers entered. Try :

```
n = []
while True:
    a=input("Enter number: ")
    try:                     #Checks if entered data is an int
        a = int(a)
    except:
        print('Entered data not an int')
        continue
    if a == 0:
        break
    n.append(a)
print(sum(n)/len(n))
```

Where the list `n` saves the entered digits as a number

Comment: Is `try: except` the cause of concern ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to have an actual list where you append the entered values:

```
lst = []
while True:
    a = int(input("Enter number: "))
    if a == 0:
        break
    else:
        lst.append(a)
print(sum(lst) / len(lst))
```

This approach still has not (yet) any error management (a user enters float numbers or any nonsense or zero at the first run, etc.). You'd need to implement this as well.

Answer (score 0):

a needs to be list of objects to use sum, in your case its not. That is why a.list doens't work. In your case you need to take inputs as int (Can be done like: `a = int(input("Enter a number"));` ) and then take the integer user inputs and append to a list (lets say its name is "ListName")(`listName.append(a)`), Then you can do this to calculate the average:

`average = sum(listName) / len(listName);`

Answer (score 0):

```
def calc_avg():
     count = 0
     sum = 0
     while True:
         try:
             new = int(input("Enter a number: "))
             if new < 0:
                 print(f'average: {sum/count}')
                 return
             sum += new
             count += 1
             print(f'sum: {sum}, numbers given: {count}')
         except ValueError:
             print("That was not a number")

calc_avg()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can loop, listen to input and update both `s` (sum) and `c` (count) variables:

```
   s, c = 0, 0
while c >= 0:
    a = int(input("Enter number: "))
    if a == 0:
        break
    else:
        s += a
    c += 1
avg = s/c
print(avg)
```